# How to create a table in my question

Tags: support, markdown

I am trying to ask a question inserting a small table that represents an Excel table to aid my explanation. I have no idea how to do this. Have tried pasting the table from the ASCII table generator but to no avail.

Comment: Note that you might need to format the whole ascii table as code (select all and then do ctrl+K or the `{}` symbol on the editor toolbar).

Comment: Many thanks. That was what I was after.

Comment: you can create ASCII table from this tool https://www.tablesgenerator.com/ and then paste in here and select all and then do ctrl+K or the {}